# Why the else part is executed everytime the result is matched

Tags: python, loops

When i give input on command line as -->stringsearch.py  joe

```
Expected Result: joe foe

Actual Result: joe foe
               No String
```

Code:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

SearchString = sys.argv[1]

def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname

def display(self): 

    if SearchString in per.fname:
        print per.fname, per.lname
    if SearchString in per.lname:
        print per.fname, per.lname
    else:
        print "No String" 

obj=[People("joe","foe"),People("lui","sui")]
for per in obj:
    per.display()
```

Where should i write the else part to get the expected ouptput

Comment: Your code is working as expected. `if SearchString in per.lname:` is false. `'joe' not in 'foe' == True`

Comment: This is some very weird code - you define "methods" that take `self` as an argument, but there's no class to be seen. Please post some code that has at least a chance to run.

Comment: where do i correct myself ?

Comment: Use the **edit** link on the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem:

```
def display(self): 

    if SearchString in per.fname:
        print per.fname, per.lname
    elif SearchString in per.lname:
        print per.fname, per.lname
    else:
        print "No String"
```

`if` statements do not form a group of alternatives themselves. To indicate that use the `elif` keyword, so the `else` part will be executed if none of the conditions were met.
In your first version, the first `if` was verified separately. After this there was a separate alternative: either `print per.fname, per.lname` if it's true that `SearchString in per.lname` or `print "No String"`, regardless of the result of the evaluation of the first `if`.

The second problem is here:

```
obj=[People("joe","foe"),People("lui","sui")]
for per in obj:
    per.display()
```

If you run the script with `joe` or `foe` as an argument in the first iteration it will print your expected result. However in the second iteration it won't match anything in the second object and prints `"No String"`.

A possible solution:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

SearchString = sys.argv[1]

class People:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

    def isMatching(self, matchString):
        return matchString in self.fname or matchString in self.lname

    def display(self): 
        print self.fname, self.lname

obj=[People("joe","foe"),People("lui","sui")]
anyMatched = False
for per in obj:
    if per.isMatching(SearchString):
        anyMatched = True
        per.display()

if not anyMatched:
    print "No String"
```

Note that the only thing I did is to make functions behave as their name says. If you stick to this simple rule it will save you a lot of trouble. Your original `display` function was doing a lot more then just "displaying" :)